# Message dequeue on exception in Mule

Tags: mule

```
<flow name="RollbackFlow">
    <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="QIN">
        <jms:transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN"/>
    </jms:inbound-endpoint>
    <component class="TestComponent"/>
    <default-exception-strategy>
       <rollback-transaction exception-pattern="*"/>
    </default-exception-strategy>
</flow>
```

In this flow when an exception is thrown by the Test component, the message is dequeued from QIN. How do I modify the flow so that message will not get dequeued from QIN?

Comment: There could be a lot of reasons.  I'd need to see your connector configuration for the JMS connector and any other global definitions around error strategies.

Comment: This is my JMS connector configuration and no other global definitions exist.                                          <jms:activemq-connector name="Active_MQ" specification="1.1" validateConnections="true" maxRedelivery="0" persistentDelivery="true" brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616?jms.prefetchPolicy.queuePrefetch=100" doc:name="Active MQ"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rollback is the default behavior, this part of the config is redundant. Next, I'm not sure what you're seeing is dequeing, otherwise the whole promise of transactions in Mule would be dysfunctional. Probably one of these 2 things are happening:

1. ActiveMQ's prefetch policy - the message is not immediately put back on the queue, try waiting for a while.
2. It gets resubmitted immediately after a rollback too many times and ends up in the dead-letter queue (DLQ) - check with AMQ web console.

Andrew

Comment: Hi Andrew there is an bug in ActiveMQ connector maxRedelivery settings in Mule3.2.1CE that breaks rollback in exception strategy.http://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-5943.              This is fixed in Mule3.3RC1.